# Python lambda with if but without else

Tags: python, lambda, inline-if

I was writing some lambda functions and couldn't figure this out. Is there a way to have something like `lambda x: x if (x<3)` in python? As `lambda a,b: a if (a > b) else b` works ok. So far `lambda x: x < 3 and x or None` seems to be the closest i have found.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A lambda, like any function, must have a return value.

`lambda x: x if (x<3)` does not work because it does not specify what to return if not `x<3`. By default functions return `None`, so you could do

```
lambda x: x if (x<3) else None
```

---

But perhaps what you are looking for is a list comprehension with an `if` condition. For example:

```
In [21]: data = [1, 2, 5, 10, -1]

In [22]: [x for x in data if x < 3]
Out[22]: [1, 2, -1]
```

Comment: @ ubuntu -- thank you. Not sure why I assumed it should return None without specifying it.

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption since functions return None by default. The important thing to remember is that what follows `lambda x:` must be an *expression*, not a statement.

Comment: @root I sometimes find it handy to think of a `lambda` as though it's actually written as `def lambda(x, y): return ...`

Answer (score 7):

I found that `filter` provided exactly what I was looking for in python 2:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 5, 10, -1]
>>> filter(lambda x: x < 3, data)
[1, 2, -1]
```

The implementation is different in [2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter): while 2.x provides a list, 3.x provides an iterator. Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) might make for a cleaner use in 3.x:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 5, 10, -1]
>>> [filter(lambda x: x < 3, data)]
[1, 2, -1]
```

Comment: The implementation is **not** the same in both 2 and 3. In 2 it returns a list, in 3 it returns an iterator, and to get it into a list, you need to convert it: `list(filter(lambda, data))`. Either way, it's generally considered easier to read a comprehension with an `if` clause like in [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709152/4518341).

Comment: Added your input about python 3, thank you! I suppose the stylistic changes are a bit about personal preference. Lambdas feel a bit natural to me due to using functional programming languages. When I read them, something like `x: x < 3` comes across as less repetitive/more elegant than something like `x for x in data if x [...]`.

Comment: Welcome! But your Python3 implementation is incorrect. You get a filter object inside a list. You need to convert it: `list(filter(lambda, data))` or use a splat: `[*filter(lambda x: x < 3, data)]`. It's also not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with `lambda x: x if x < 3 else None`?

Comment: my understanding is that list comprehension is more appropriate in this scenario

Comment: The question doesn't mention iteration, so I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: x will have a value of "None" in case of else

Comment: @Mardini No, but the `lambda` will return None in that case. It has to return _something_.

Comment: @user4815162342 This is exactly what I meant, lambda will return "None"

Comment: @Mardini You formulate it as an issue with the answer. What would you expect it to return instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can always try to invoke 'filter' for conditional checks. Fundamentally, `map()` has to work on every occurrence of the iterables, so it cannot pick and choose. But filter may help narrow down the choices. For example, I create a list from 1 to 19 but want to create a tuple **of** squares of only even numbers.

```
x = list(range(1,20))

y = tuple(map(lambda n: n**2, filter(lambda n: n%2==0,x)))

print (y)
```

Comment: The answers I was looking for, Thanks.
If somehow you can manage to add a 'reduce' statement here and boom we can have one liner functional programming tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ellipsis `...` to fill `else` statement

```
lambda x: x if (x<3) else ...
```

Note it does not work with `pass`.